# HAproxy gives no OCSP response back: Response not sent

Tags: ssl, openssl, haproxy, ocsp

I just can't manage to get an OCSP response. Here are the steps I did:

Haproxy cert directory:

1. Added CA file containing root and intermediate CA certificates with .issuer extension.
2. Added my .pem cert file including private key, crt etc

Generated OCSP response in DER format with openssl:

```
openssl ocsp -issuer my_cert.issuer -VAfile my_cert.issuer -cert my_cert.pem -url http://status.thawte.com -header Host status.thawte.com -no_nonce -respout my_cert.ocsp
    Response verify OK
    my_cert.pem: good
        This Update: Mar 14 17:45:00 2022 GMT
        Next Update: Mar 21 17:00:00 2022 GMT
```

3 files are now in my HAproxy cert directory:

- my_cert.issuer
- my_cert.ocsp
- my_cert.pem

This is how my HAproxy config looks like:

```
global
  maxconn 4096
  ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:RSA+AES128:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH:!CAMELLIA
  log 127.0.0.1 local0 debug

defaults
  log     global
  mode    http
  option  httplog
  option  dontlognull
  option forwardfor
  option http-server-close
  stats enable
  stats uri /stats
  timeout connect 3000ms
  timeout client 25000ms
  timeout server 25000ms

frontend ssl_check
    bind :::80
    bind :::443 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/certs/my_cert.pem
    acl https ssl_fc
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto http  if !https
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if https
    mode http
    use_backend %[base,lower,map_beg(/usr/local/etc/haproxy/ssl.map)] if { base,lower,map_beg(/usr/local/etc/haproxy/ssl.map) -m found }
    default_backend ssl_check

backend ssl_check
  mode http
  errorfile 503 /usr/local/etc/haproxy/errors/certificate_response.http
```

This is how my fake backend looks like using a manipulated 503 errorfile giving response 200 back:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain

200 Found
```

Reloaded HAproxy afterwards but I get still the same output:

```
$ echo quit | openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -tlsextdebug -status
CONNECTED(00000003)
TLS server extension "renegotiation info" (id=65281), len=1
0001 - <SPACES/NULS>
TLS server extension "EC point formats" (id=11), len=4
0000 - 03 00 01 02                                       ....
TLS server extension "session ticket" (id=35), len=0
OCSP response: no response sent
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = Thawte RSA CA 2018
verify return:1
[...]
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/[...]
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=Thawte RSA CA 2018
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=Thawte RSA CA 2018
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Global Root CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Global Root CA
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Global Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[...]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/[...]
issuer=/
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4377 bytes and written 441 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: FDAA738CD5049E2D14F5F7AD1C2CBCA36B938B94755F697E4CE0DCD40342791E
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: [...]
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
[...]

    Start Time: 1647360170
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
DONE
C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=Thawte RSA CA 2018
```

This is how the HAproxy package is setup regarding to OpenSSL etc:

```
# haproxy -vv
HA-Proxy version 1.8.19 2019/02/11
Copyright 2000-2019 Willy Tarreau <willy@haproxy.org>

Build options :
  TARGET  = linux2628
  CPU     = generic
  CC      = gcc
  CFLAGS  = -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdeclaration-after-statement -fwrapv -Wno-null-dereference -Wno-unused-label
  OPTIONS = USE_ZLIB=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_LUA=1 USE_PCRE=1

Default settings :
  maxconn = 2000, bufsize = 16384, maxrewrite = 1024, maxpollevents = 200

Built with OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018
Running on OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018
OpenSSL library supports TLS extensions : yes
OpenSSL library supports SNI : yes
OpenSSL library supports : TLSv1.0 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
Built with Lua version : Lua 5.3.3
Built with transparent proxy support using: IP_TRANSPARENT IPV6_TRANSPARENT IP_FREEBIND
Encrypted password support via crypt(3): yes
Built with multi-threading support.
Built with PCRE version : 8.39 2016-06-14
Running on PCRE version : 8.39 2016-06-14
PCRE library supports JIT : no (USE_PCRE_JIT not set)
Built with zlib version : 1.2.8
Running on zlib version : 1.2.8
Compression algorithms supported : identity("identity"), deflate("deflate"), raw-deflate("deflate"), gzip("gzip")
Built with network namespace support.

Available polling systems :
      epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result OK
Total: 3 (3 usable), will use epoll.

Available filters :
    [SPOE] spoe
    [COMP] compression
    [TRACE] trace
```

Tested it on a docker-compose setup and on a live machine also but in both cased I get ther certificate chain back etc but the OCSP response field is still empty:

```
OCSP response: no response sent
```

What am i doing wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

Was able to sort it out. The naming convention of the certificate file name must be followed and was wrong.

Wrong:

- my_cert.issuer
- my_cert.ocsp
- my_cert.pem

Correct:

- my_cert.pem.issuer
- my_cert.pem.ocsp
- my_cert.pem

Then I was able to get an OCSP response from my HAproxy test instance back.